# Should build stage be in Dockerfile?

Tags: continuous-integration, docker, continuous-delivery

I personally put build stage in Dockerfile. (Using multi-stage feature in Dockerfile)

But in my company, we have dev containers where all dependencies are installed and managed. So in our product's Dockerfile, there is no build stage. Build(compile) is done on dev containers and result binary are copied to Dockerfile. (Using COPY ofcourse)

But I personally think this is somewhat uncomfortable. Even though dev containers are there to guarantee consistant build output, it feels like we are only using half of Docker's abilities.

My teammate says we are only using docker for keeping consistency in production environment so using docker in build stage is not an interest.

Is this argument valid? what are the drawbacks and pitfalls?

Comment: It sounds like what your teammate is saying is that, when building new features, they want the ability to change the docker environment variables on local dev containers, that are expected to be volatile, and only change production environment variables once a development environment is confirmed to be working as expected. and copied to production. Is that understanding of your environment correct?

Comment: @AlexanderThe1st But our build environment is already fixed and will not change much. And that is why we could set up local dev containers. So I'm suggesting to move build stage to Dockerfile because then, you can develop in any environment you want but for production build, it is guaranteed to be consistant. This way local developement environment can be volatile too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the language used. If you are developing in Node or Java for example, environment variables like path can determine which version of the framework you are using. Compiling in a Docker container can be super useful as you can have many projects all using different frameworks and compilers on the same PC but when you build you don't have to worry about the dev PCs path vars, what version of java runtime is installed etc. Its super useful to be able to build in a container and know exactly what the setting are.

However, lets say "more mature" languages have long had these same issues and already have ways of dealing with the issue without needing a containers. If you have a build pipeline with a make file, or azure or teamcity pipelines. You don't have these problems, or rather, you have already dealt with them. Compiling inside a container is an extra set which can complicate an already complicated build. All you want is to package the existing published binaries in a container package.

Comment: good point. my company is using golang and build process is managed by Makefile. But there are things that cannot be controlled by Makefile which can be managed through Docker. I think using local dev containers also somewhat simliar but it locks attempts to change environments for experimenting purpose. I think we should freely develop in any envrionment allowing different experimentation but once confirmed applied to build stage in Dockerfile.